# Markov and Chebyshew inequality for geometrical variable

Tags: probability, inequality

Let $X\tilde{} Geom(p)$.  What estimations can we achieve using Markov's  and Chebyshev's inequality?

In case Markov's inequality it is:
$$Pr(X\ge c) \le \frac{EX}{c}=\frac{1}{pc}$$

However, in terms of Chebyshev's inequality I can't deal with: $|X-EX|$.  Can you help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are interested in $\Pr(X \geq c)$, the one-sided Chebyshev inequality is a better choice here. The one-sided Chebyshev inequality is of the following form:
$$
\Pr(X - \mathbb{E}[X] \geq a) \leq \frac{Var[X]}{Var[X] + a^2} \tag{$\clubsuit$}
$$
By substituting $a = c - \mathbb{E}[X]$ in the inequality above, we have
$$
\Pr(X \geq c)\leq \frac{Var[X]}{Var[X] + (c - \mathbb{E}[X])^2}
$$

Comment: Why $a=c-EX ?$ For me, $a=c+EX$

Comment: @Happyman $X - \mathbb{E}[X] \geq c - \mathbb{E}[X] \Leftrightarrow X \geq c$

Comment: yeah, of course.

Answer (score 0):

$|X-E[X]|\geq c$ is in fact $$ X \in [\frac1p -c, \frac1p +c] $$ so you could get an estimation about the interval in which $X$ is